# help in cmakelists.txt

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,I need to that what should i do in cmakelists.txt http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BGV9NAmQ since i am getting this error  (target_link_libraries):   Cannot specify link libraries for target "ptedit_1" which is not built by   this project.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37144/help-in-cmakelists.txt/) by [user456](https://answers.ros.org/users/2701/user456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error is because you are trying to link to a library "ptedit_1" which still do not exist. You probably expect cmake->makefile->make to generate "ptedit_1" library.

You must add following command to CMakeList.txt.

```
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} your_source_files)
```

This will result in required library. Command **target_link_libraries( ptedit_1 ${KDE4_KDEUI_LIBS} )** must come after rosbuild command.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1